# MySQLi - JS - drop down multi select

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

beginner here.
Made a drop down where you can select 3 options that i would have placed in my 3 place holders in my database.
In other words, i have 3 attribute records "at1. at2, at3" and a drop down of attributes, like "Red, Blue, Black, Orange, Green" (in the code below, for the moment i just labeled them "one, two, three") that i want placed into  at1, at2, at3.

So.. so far i have..

```
 $at0 = $_POST['at0'];
  $at1 = $_POST['at1'];
  $at2 = $_POST['at2'];
```

And

```
<style>
                              .multiselect {
                                width: 200px;
                              }
                              .selectBox {
                                position: relative;
                              }  
                              .selectBox select {
                                width: 100%;
                                font-weight: bold;
                              }
                              .overSelect {
                                position: absolute;
                                left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
                              }
                              #checkboxes {
                                display: none;
                                border: 1px #dadada solid;
                              }
                              #checkboxes label {
                                display: block;
                              }
                              #checkboxes label:hover {
                                background-color: #1e90ff;
                              }
                              </style>

                      Attributes:
                        <div class="multiselect">
                          <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
                            <select>
                              <option>Select an option</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="overSelect"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div id="checkboxes">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="at0" id="one" /> one
                            <label for="two"><input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two" />two
                            <label for="three"><input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three" />three




                          </div>
                        </div>

                                  <script>
                                    var expanded = false;
                                    function showCheckboxes() {
                                      var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
                                      if (!expanded) {
                                        checkboxes.style.display = "block";
                                        expanded = true;
                                      } else {
                                        checkboxes.style.display = "none";
                                        expanded = false;

                                        }
                                    }
                                  </script>
```

Is there an easier/cleaner way to have a user select multiple options which all get put in my database?
At the moment it kind of works, when i click on the first checkbox, the word "On" is left in 'at1' in my database.. How do i get what i want to achieve?

Comment: Anyone?!?!?!??! Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/checkbox

The input checkbox will pass the default "on" if checked.

You can pass a custom value using:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="at0" id="one" value="mycustomvalue" />
```

That will make the POST or GET (depending on your form) var "at0" to receive the value "mycustomvalue" if the checkbox is checked.

**EDIT:**

If you want multiple checkboxes that may or not be checked you can use the array syntax for the name. That is:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="one" value="valueone" />
<input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="two" value="valuetwo" />
<input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="three" value="valuethree" />
<input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="four" value="valuefour" />
```

If you check boxes 1 and 3, the PHP part will be

PHP:

```
echo $_POST["at0"][0]; // will echo "valueone";
echo $_POST["at0"][1]; // will echo "valuethree";
```

Then it's matter of you how you save that into the DB. Just remember to sanitize your inputs to avoid SQL Injection Attacks

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what i was looking for! appreciate your patience with my beginner confusion and frustration.  
So, at the moment i have 3 check boxes and 3 spaces in my database.. Is there a way for me to make say 20 check boxes, and whatever 3 are chosen get thrown into database slot 1, 2, 3?

Comment: That would probably work better if you change the "name" of each input from at01, at02 at03 to at0[], that will mean that at0 is an array containing each value from any inputs with that name. So let's say checkbox it has value="something1" and checkbox2 has value="something2" and both has name="at0[]" then you will receive $_POST["at0"] = array("something1", "something2") if both are checked. That way you can loop this array and insert in your db

Comment: Would they all be put into the at0 column in my database, separated by a comma or something?

Comment: That's why you need to loop them first and order them as you want them to be inserted (something like at0[0] into at1, at0[1] into at2 and so on)

Comment: sorry having difficulty with the concept.. at the moment i have $at0 = $_POST['at0']; _______
<input type="checkbox" name="at0" id="one" value="red"/>red
__________________You're saying change it to____________<input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="one" value="red"/> <input type="checkbox" name="at0[]" id="two" value="blue"/>

Comment: and change $at0 = $_POST['at0']; ____to____ $_POST['at0'] =$at0[]; ... in a way..

Comment: $_POST["at0"][0] will be the first element of the array or more clearly, the first checkbox checked. $_POST["at0"][1] will be the second, and so on.

Comment: Awesome... so does this make sense____ $at0 = $_POST["at0"][0]; _____
  $at1 = $_POST["at0"][1];______
  $at2 = $_POST["at0"][2];

Comment: oh and... fixing my mysqli query im not sure what to do____ $query = "INSERT INTO tableinfo (at0, at1, at2) VALUES ('$at0', '$at1', '$at2')"; ___should i INSERT INTO tableinfo (at0[], at0[], at0[])

Comment: yes, that does makes sense, and doing so you can use your query just as it is.

Comment: Leave my query how it was? but im no longer using at1 and at2 in the html?

Comment: If you use `$at0 = $_POST["at0"][0]; $at1 = $_POST["at0"][1]; $at2 = $_POST["at0"][2];` like you said in the previous comment it will work